# Conexión a base de datos con Typeorm y Socket.io

Tags: sql-server, typescript, socket.io, mssql, typeorm

Estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos con typeorm y Socket.io con Typescript. Quiero hacer una simple select pero me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a cambiar el nombre del modelo y está claro que de ahí viene el problema ya que al cambiarlo, sale un error de undefined. En principio me gustaría hacer solamente select a esa tabla de la base de datos por lo que con tener una select bien hecha me solucionaría todo.
Pongo el código por si a alguno se le ocurre qué puede estar pasando:

index.ts:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import app from './app';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

createConnection();
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server on port', app.get('port'));
})

import SocketIO from 'socket.io';
import { getPset, insertPset } from './Events/Pset.events';
const io = SocketIO(server);
io.on('connection', async(socket) => {
    // pset
    insertPset(socket, io)
   // getPset(io)
})
```

Modelo:

```
import { Entity, BaseEntity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";


@Entity()
export class PSET extends BaseEntity{

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    PS_ID?:number;
    @Column()
    PS_Number?:number;
    @Column()
    PS_TorqueUnit?:number;
    @Column()
    PS_TighteningUnitId?:number;
    @Column()
    PS_Comment?:string;
    @Column()
    PS_Version?:number;

}
```

Controller:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';


import { PSET } from "../models/Pset";
import { getConnection, getRepository } from "typeorm";

export async function getPsets(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
    try {
        const psets = await getConnection()
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .select('PSET')
            .from(PSET, 'PSET')
            .getMany()
        return res.json(psets)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return res.status(500).send(error)
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
import { Router } from "express";

const router: Router = Router();

import { getPsets } from "../controllers/psetController";

router.route('/')
    .get(getPsets)


export default router;
```

Event:

```
import { Socket } from "socket.io";
import { getConnection } from "typeorm";
import { PSET } from "../models/Pset";

export function insertPset(socket:Socket, io:any){
    socket.on('insert:PSET', async(data:PSET) => {
        console.log('DATA')
        console.log(data)
        await PSET.insert(data);
        await getPset(io)
    })
}


export async function getPset(io:any){
    const psets = await getConnection()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('PSET')
        .from(PSET,'PSET')
        .getMany()
    io.socket.emit('PSET', psets)
}
```

No se que puede estar fallando. Sí alguno tiene una idea para que me pueda resolver el problema :^)